# Host web site on mac server to run sql queries

Tags: sql, macos

I have a web site that needs to talk to two different databases, one is oracle, the other is SQL server.  The web site is being hosted on mac server 10.5.  What would be the easiest way to get my web page talking to these two databases?  PHP?  JDBC?  Perl?  Something else?  So far I haven't gotten anything to work.

Answer (score 1):

Most frameworks such as Django/Rails etc should talk with two databases. The fact that it's a Mac Server is probably largely irrelevant. You should pick a language/framework and ask the appropriate questions about talking to two database engines.